# TypeError: Production Build on Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, production-environment, dev-to-production

I have been worked with nuxt recently.
 My code work well on development environment.
When i run npm run build and starting the project on production environment, 
I found an error without much help with error code or else.
[This was my app with error without any spesific path and else](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9nDm.jpg)

[This was my app on development environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u0Ir.jpg)

This error happen when I try to add vue-awesome-swiper and vue-carousel at the same time.
With conditional rendering of course.
Its work well first when i just use vue-awesome-swiper only or vue-carousel only.
But suddenly its crashing when I try to add both of them.
And now, its giving the same error when I try to use just one of them or removing both of them.

Can someone help me with this error please.
This was my code on vue-awesome-swiper.

```
<v-container 
@mouseover="showNavButtons()"
@mouseleave="hideNavButtons()"
fluid 
v-if="sub_categories" 
class="pa-0 pb-5 pt-3">
<client-only>
  <Swiper 
    :class="`swiper pb-6 ${!$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly ? 'pl-1 pr-2 pt-3':'pl-2 pr-15'}`" 
    :options="swiperOption"
    :auto-destroy="true" 
    ref="swiper"
    :delete-instance-on-destroy="true"
    :cleanup-styles-on-destroy="true"
    >
    <swiper-slide v-for="sub_category in sub_categories" :key="sub_category.id" class="mt-10">
      <v-card height="250px" class="overflow-hidden" style="box-shadow:2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);">
        <v-img width="100%" height="100%" lazy-src="/images/abu.jpg" :src="subCategoryImageSource(sub_category.name) ? subCategoryImageSource(sub_category.name) : sub_category.image ? sub_category.thumbnail_link : `/images/category_photo.png`"/>
        <v-row class="position-absolute" style="top: 95px; left: 40px">
          <v-col cols="12" class="pa-0">
            <span class="d-block black--text letter-spacing text-left gt-walsheim-regular pb-1">SHOP</span>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" class="pa-0">
            <span class="letter-spacing main-color text-uppercase dosis-bold" style="font-size: 1.25rem" v-html="breakWords(sub_category.name)">
              </span> 
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        
        <v-row class="position-absolute" style="bottom: 20px; left: 40px">
          <router-link :to="`/categories/${category_slug}/sub-categories/${sub_category.slug}`" >
            <v-btn outlined class="main-color letter-spacing d-block mt-2 px-5 button-hover-primary category-card-button dosis-semi-bold border-hover-primary">SHOP NOW</v-btn>
          </router-link>
        </v-row>
        <router-link :to="`/categories/${category_slug}/sub-categories/${sub_category.slug}`">
        </router-link>
      </v-card>
    </swiper-slide>
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar" slot="scrollbar" style="bottom: 0px"></div>
  </Swiper>
</client-only>
```

this was my code on vue-carousel.

```
<v-container 
@mouseover="showNavButtons()"
@mouseleave="hideNavButtons()"
fluid v-if="sub_categories" 
class="pa-0 pb-5 pt-3">
<client-only>
  <div v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp" style="display:flex; justify-content:center">
    <carousel
      class="sub-category-carousel"
      :navigationEnabled="navigation" 
      :autoplayHoverPause="true" 
      :autoplay="false"  
      :paginationPadding="0" 
      paginationActiveColor="#b3b3b3"
      navigationNextLabel="<img src='/icons/next.png' class='slider-navigation'></img>"
      navigationPrevLabel="<img src='/icons/previous.png' class='slider-navigation'></img>" 
      :autoplayTimeout="5000" 
      paginationColor="white" 
      paginationPosition="top"
      :style="`width: ${$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown ? '85%' : '100%'};`"
      :loop="true"
      :centerMode="true"
      :perPageCustom="[[100, 1], [700, 2], [1700, 3]]"
    > 
      <slide v-for="sub_category in sub_categories" :key="sub_category.id">
        <v-col cols="12" class="pa-0 pb-5 text-center px-3">
          <v-card height="250px" class="overflow-hidden" style="box-shadow:2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);">
            <div class="position-relative grey-background overflow-hidden category-card">
              <v-img 
                v-if="sub_category.image"
                :src="subCategoryImageSource(sub_category.name) ? subCategoryImageSource(sub_category.name) : sub_category.image ? sub_category.thumbnail_link : `/images/category_photo.png`"
                lazy-src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkqAcAAIUAgUW0RjgAAAAASUVORK5CYII="
                :title="sub_category.name" 
                width="100%"
                height="100%"
                class="position-absolute" 
                >
                <template v-slot:placeholder>
                  <v-row
                    class="fill-height ma-0"
                    align="center"
                    justify="center"
                  >
                    <v-progress-circular indeterminate color="grey lighten-5"></v-progress-circular>
                  </v-row>
                </template>
              </v-img>
              <div class="category-carousel-container pa-5 pl-5">
                <span class="d-block category-card-shop letter-spacing text-left dosis-semi-bold">SHOP</span>
                <div class="category-card-name-container">
                  <span class="letter-spacing main-color text-left text-uppercase dosis-semi-bold table-caption category-title dosis-bold">{{ sub_category.name }}</span> 
                </div>
                <router-link :to="`/categories/${category_slug}/sub-categories/${sub_category.slug}`">
                  <v-btn outlined class="main-color letter-spacing d-block mt-2 px-5 button-hover-primary category-card-button gt-walsheim-pro-medium border-hover-primaryC">SHOP NOW</v-btn>
                </router-link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </slide>
    </carousel>
  </div>
</client-only>
```

this was the parent component when I use the children component

```
<v-container fluid class="px-0 pt-3 pb-0">
<v-row class="mb-5 px-0" v-for="category in featured_categories" :key="category.id">
  <v-layout justify-center align-center>
    <v-col v-if="loading" cols="12">
      <LazyLoading />
    </v-col>
    <v-col 
      xl="9"
      lg="10"
      sm="12"
      md="10"
      cols="12"
      :class="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown ? 'pa-0 pl-5':'pa-0'">
      <div>
        <LazyHomeHeaderHomeComponentIcon :content="'SHOP BY ' + `<br class='hidden-md-and-up'>` + category.name" />
      </div>

      <div v-if="width >= 600">
        <LazyCarouselSubCategory :sub_categories="category.sub_categories" :category_slug="category.slug" />
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <LazySwiperSubCategory :sub_categories="category.sub_categories" :category_slug="category.slug" />
      </div>
      <v-layout justify-center class="pb-5">
        <v-btn class="main-background-color white--text letter-spacing px-8 button-hover-secondary dosis-semi-bold" :to="`/categories/${category.slug}`">VIEW ALL</v-btn>
      </v-layout>
    </v-col>
  </v-layout>
</v-row>
```

I really appreciate the help, thanks before.

Comment: Parent component have the closing tag, i just miss copied my code. sorry

Answer (score 0):

I found the solutions.
The images seems to be crashing on production build, when i change with static images its work well.
So if someone having the same issues, try to commenting all your assets,